Python interactive plot: select a line in a 2D plot (with color as height information) of .xyz data and plot the profile along the selected line
I have a .xyz data that includes x and y coordinates and z as height of each x, y point. I want to plot the data: x and y axis are the coordinates and z is shown as a color scale. In this plot, I want to select a line with right (start point) and left (end point) mouse click, and I want to get a plot of the profile along this line: x-axis should be the segment length and y axis should have height data i.e. z value at each point along the line connecting the start and end point.
The xyz look like this:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

"""

import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open a file dialog to select the .xyz file
#Tk().withdraw()  # Hide the Tkinter root window
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("XYZ Files", "*.xyz")])

# Read the .xyz file into a pandas DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=" ", header=None, names=["X", "Y", "Z"], skiprows=14,skipfooter=1, engine='python')

# Access the data
print(data.head())  # Print the first few rows of the DataFrame


x = np.unique(data['X'])
y = np.unique(data['Y'])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = data['Z'].values.reshape(len(y), len(x))

# Fit a plane to the data points
A = np.column_stack((X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), np.ones(X.size)))
coefficients, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, Z.flatten(), rcond=None)
plane = np.dot(A, coefficients).reshape(X.shape)

# Subtract the plane from the original surface
Z_corrected = Z - plane  # Correct the surface level by subtracting the mean value of Z

# Create a figure for the 2D plot
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

# Plot the 2D plot with color-coded height information
im = ax2.imshow(Z_corrected, cmap='viridis', extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()], origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax2, label='Z Corrected')

# Set labels and title
ax2.set_xlabel('X')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y')
ax2.set_title('2D Plot with Color-coded Height')

plt.show()

# Create a figure and a 3D axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the surface, enter in console for interactive plot %matplotlib qt 
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_corrected, cmap='viridis')

# Set labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('Surface Plot')

# Show the interactive plot
# find the coefficients of the best plane fit
start_x, start_y = None, None # Initialize start and end points
end_x, end_y = None, None

def onclick(event):
 global start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y

 if event.button == 3:  # Right mouse button
     start_x, start_y = event.xdata, event.ydata
     print("Start point selected: ", start_x, start_y)
 if event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button
     end_x, end_y =event.xdata, event.ydata
     print("End point selected: ", end_x, end_y)
     if start_x > end_x:
         start_x, end_x = end_x, start_x
     if start_y > end_y:
         start_y, end_y = end_y, start_y
     # Find the corresponding indices in the X and Y arrays
     start_index = np.argmin(np.abs(x - start_x)) # how do I correct the starting and end points to select the points from X, Y mesh grid? or is there a better way to do this instead of working with a meshgrid?
     end_index = np.argmin(np.abs(x - end_x)) #Also I want the start and end y points to be defined as well. 

     # Extract the segment of the original surface
     segment = Z_corrected[:, start_index:end_index + 1] # the start and end y points should also be selected.

     # the axis values for the segment
     segment_length = abs(end_x - start_x)
     segment_axis = np.linspace(0, segment_length, segment.shape[1])

     # Plot the 2D profile of the segment
     plt.figure()
     plt.plot(segment_axis, segment.mean(axis=0)) # I don't want to plot a mean of each line but every z value at each point along the selected line.
     plt.xlabel('Length')
     plt.ylabel('Z')
     plt.title('Segment Profile')
     plt.show()

     # Plot the start and end points on the surface plot
     ax2.scatter(start_x, start_y, Z_corrected[np.argmin(np.abs(y - start_y)), start_index], c='r', label='Start')
     ax2(end_x, end_y, Z_corrected[np.argmin(np.abs(y - end_y)), end_index], c='g', s=50, label='End')

     # Add a legend
     ax2.legend()

     # Reset start and end points for next selection
     start_x, start_y = None, None
     end_x, end_y = None, None

# Connect the mouse click event to the onclick function
cid = fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()

The issue is when selecting the start and end points on the original plot, the code looks for the x and y values in the array and not meshgrid. Even if I looked for the x and y points in the meshgrid, the resulting segment is not a line but a matrix (Z points on the grid). That is why the plotting of segment only works if the mean value is plotted. How can I change this code, to draw the line and the z profile along the selected points? Also, in the profile plot that is generated after clicking on the start and end points, I want to get the height value at each point of the line connecting the two points and not a mean value.
